# Why doesn't TestNG show us in the "Debug As" dialog in eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, unit-testing, eclipse-plugin, testng

Using eclipse indigo and the 6.3.2 version of the TestNG plugin on CentOS.

The TestNG plugin seems to be installed successfully.  I can launch TestNG tests by right-clicking on a class in Package Explorer and choosing "Debug As" -> "TestNG Test".  However, if I hit the Debug icon in the toolbar at the top of the screen, TestNG does not appear as an option in the "Debug As" dialog.  It gives me JUnit as an option, but not TestNG.  Is this a bug?  Or am I just not set up correctly?

Comment: Are you sure you're using TestNG annotations in your source?

Comment: Thanks!  That was the problem.  Sorry, I'm new to TestNG.